# Sql Join and Sum using Coalesce

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

```
select
    COA.AccountNo
    ,AccountName
    ,(coalesce(DVDebit, 0) + coalesce(JVDebit, 0) + coalesce(CTDebit, 0))   as Debit
    ,(coalesce(CVCredit, 0) + coalesce(JVCredit, 0))                        as Credit
from ChartOfAccounts as COA
    left join
    (
        select
            AccountNo
            ,sum(Credit) as CVCredit
        from CreditVouchersBody
        group by AccountNo
    ) as CreditVoucher
        on COA.AccountNo = CreditVoucher.AccountNo
    left join
    (
        select
            AccountNo
            ,sum(Debit) as DVDebit
        from DebitVouchersBody
        group by AccountNo
    ) as DebitVoucher
        on COA.AccountNo = DebitVoucher.AccountNo
    left join
    (
        select
            AccountNo
            ,sum(Debit) as JVDebit
            ,sum(Credit) as JVCredit
        from JournalVouchersBody
        group by AccountNo
    ) as JournalVoucher
        on COA.AccountNo = JournalVoucher.AccountNo
    left join
    (
        select
            AccountNoPayTo
            ,sum(Amount) as CTDebit
        from BankCheques
        group by AccountNoPayTo
    ) as BankdCheque
        on COA.AccountNo = BankdCheque.AccountNoPayTo
where
    COA.IsDetailed      = 'True'
    and COA.AccountType = 'Expense';
```

This query was working fine and was taking values as per requirements. But now i have changed nothing in query but database values i changed, and this query is returning only 0. there are values in some tables in database. Can any one help me where i am wrong in this.

Comment: Kindly share your schema, sample data and desired output in text format

Comment: I can't read that query. Too much side-ways scrolling. Rer-format it, including line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Does "returning only 0" means that it returns zero for the sums or do you mean that it doesn't return any rows?

If you mean that the sums are zero, then most likely the join doesn't work anymore. Have you changed the AccountNo in ChartOfAccounts or in the other tables?

If it doesn't return any rows, you have to check ChartOfAccounts, because the left joins won't reduce the number of rows you get.

If there are values in ChartOfAccounts, check the values of IsDetailed and AccountType and compare them against your where condition.

`select distinct IsDetailed from ChartOfAccounts`

`select distinct AccountType from ChartOfAccounts`

For the others: This is his query in a readable form:

```
select
    COA.AccountNo
    ,AccountName
    ,(coalesce(DVDebit, 0) + coalesce(JVDebit, 0) + coalesce(CTDebit, 0))   as Debit
    ,(coalesce(CVCredit, 0) + coalesce(JVCredit, 0))                        as Credit
from ChartOfAccounts as COA
    left join
    (
        select
            AccountNo
            ,sum(Credit) as CVCredit
        from CreditVouchersBody
        group by AccountNo
    ) as CreditVoucher
        on COA.AccountNo = CreditVoucher.AccountNo
    left join
    (
        select
            AccountNo
            ,sum(Debit) as DVDebit
        from DebitVouchersBody
        group by AccountNo
    ) as DebitVoucher
        on COA.AccountNo = DebitVoucher.AccountNo
    left join
    (
        select
            AccountNo
            ,sum(Debit) as JVDebit
            ,sum(Credit) as JVCredit
        from JournalVouchersBody
        group by AccountNo
    ) as JournalVoucher
        on COA.AccountNo = JournalVoucher.AccountNo
    left join
    (
        select
            AccountNoPayTo
            ,sum(Amount) as CTDebit
        from BankCheques
        group by AccountNoPayTo
    ) as BankdCheque
        on COA.AccountNo = BankdCheque.AccountNoPayTo
where
    COA.IsDetailed      = 'True'
    and COA.AccountType = 'Expense';
```